# Script to remove parts of a filename

Tags: windows, filesystems, filenames, windows-scripting

I am looking for a way to remove parts of my file names (big folder). I don't want to rename them all but I merely want to have an output of the edited file names in a text document or clipboard.

They all follow the similar pattern. The initial part of my file names are randomized by the system. I am not sure how to proceed in terms of what to use to complete the first part. Here is an example filename:

1231230#p9999_w_e_aa.jpg

I want to extract 9999 part (the part between the #p and the first underscore).

*The machine I'm currently working from is running Windows 7.*